# Prove that non-zero entire function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non-zero entire function such as $\frac{Re(f)}{Re(f)^2 + Im(f)^2}$ is a bounded function.

Show that $f$ is constant.

I know how to show that $f$ is constant if the real or imaginery part of $f$ is bounded, but I can't see how to implement it here.

Maybe to find a smaller expression that is bounded too?

Any insights?

Comment: $=(1/f+1/\overline{f})/2=Re(1/f)$. Then you know how to do this one too.

Comment: If $Re(\frac{1}{f})$ is bounded is $Re(f)$ necessarily bounded too? I guess it is.

Comment: If $Re(1/f)$ is bounded you know how to prove that $1/f$ is constant. Therefore, $f$ is constant too.